# Finding Repeat Emails within 3 time Ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

So basically I have a list of events and the attendees. I want to try to find repeat attendees.

REPEAT STATUS BASED ON ATTENDEE'S RSVP EMAIL

IN THIS CASE, A REPEAT ATTENDEE IS DEFINED AS SOMEONE WHO RSVP'D TO AT LEAST ONE EVENT IN EACH TIME RANGE

4/10/19 - 7/1/19

8/2/19 - 9/7/19

9/18/18 - 10/16/2019

Is it possible to do this in Excel? Thanks guys!

Comment: Most likely doable using some Countifs

Comment: Please share some sample data with expected output. Seeing your data structure in one row does not explain the relationships between each data.